# DateTime column doesn't update

Tags: asp.net, datetime, sql-server-2012, sql-update

This is how I declare the variable which stores my DateTime.

```
private static  System.DateTime columndate_defaultValue = System.DateTime.Now;
```

And this is how I update my table when I click a button from my aspx web page:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE TBL_RETETA_TRANDAFIR SET TradTempSol=@TradTempSol, TradTempAir=@TradTempAir, DateTime=@DateTime", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", columndate_defaultValue);
```

My problem is that when I click the second time on the update button, the values are updated, but the DateTime remains the same as when pressed the first time the update button.

To understand beeter my problem:
Let's say I make the first update on 2016-04-04 12:44:15.

If after 5 minutes I want to make a new update, the DateTime is the same: 2016-04-04 12:44:15.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When exactly do you declare your variable? It takes the value from the time you declare the variable. Why not do `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", System.DateTime.Now);`?

Comment: I declare above the update method.

Comment: You should show more of your code to understand what happens.

Comment: I replaced with `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", System.DateTime.Now);` and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use GetDate() or GetUtcDate() if you are not handling timezones. Then you don't have to pass in the date parameter.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE TBL_RETETA_TRANDAFIR SET TradTempSol=@TradTempSol, TradTempAir=@TradTempAir, DateTime=GetDate()", connection);
```